# Как проверить работает ли DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть след. скрипт:

```sql
begin  
    dbms_parallel_execute.create_task('MASSCHANGE2');
    dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_rowid(task_name   => 'MASSCHANGE2',
                                                 table_owner => 'FMC',
                                                 table_name  => 'FMC_MASSCHANGE',
                                                 by_row      => true,
                                                 chunk_size  => 10000);
    dbms_parallel_execute.run_task(task_name      => 'MASSCHANGE2',
                                   sql_stmt       => 'begin fmc.pkg_fmc_masschange.fmc_masschange( :start_id, :end_id ); end;',
                                   language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                   parallel_level => parallel_level);
    dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task('MASSCHANGE2');  
end;
```

Если запустить данный скрипт, то по времени нет никакой разницы если запускать процедуру отдельно без `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE`

Comment: Как вы мерите быстрей или не быстрей? Что у вас в процедуре?

Comment: Раз не выпадает ошибка и функция не выполняется, то точно работает. Ваш вопрос наверное о том, работает ли ваша процедура в несколько потоков. Об этом сложно судить не видя, что внутри вашей процедуры

Comment: @0xdb Опишу примерный принцип процедуры, так как там более 2000 тыс строк то думаю сюда прикладывать нет смысла. Есть таблица в которой примерно 1000 строк. В процедуре запускаю курсор и обрабатываю каждую запись(вызов гфа, проверки всякие, обновляю статусы и тд). Обработка одной записи примерно 3-4 сек, то есть это примерно час на 1000 записей. Так вот если запускать процедуру в параллели при помощи dbms_parallel_execute то по времени она также бежит почти час +- мин 5-10. Отсюда у меня и возникает вопрос, как проверить что процедура запускается в нужное мне количество потоков?

Comment: Хмм, у вас таблица 1000 строк, а задаёте chunk_size=>10000. Сколько потоков вы ожидаете? В  ответе я уже указал, где можно посмотреть, как прошло выполнение.

Comment: @0xdb это я указал как пример 1000 строк, таблица все время обновляется. В chunk_size задаю количество строк в таблице. Потоки задаю половину от количества процов на сервере

Comment: Хорошо, "В chunk_size задаю количество строк в таблице", то есть rowcount/chunk_size=1, или другими словами, все строчки будут обработаны в **одном** job slave. Ещё раз, посмотрите пожалуйста в представлениях, указанных в ответе, как проходит выполнение. Там детально показано распределение строк, где и как долго выполняются отдельные куски (chank).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полную информацию о выполнении задачи можно получить из представлений `user_parallel_execute_tasks` и `user_parallel_execute_chunks`. Например:

```
select 
    status, job_name, count (1) chanks, 
    sum (((end_ts+0)-(start_ts+0))*24*60*60) total_duration_sec
from user_parallel_execute_chunks
where task_name = 'testpe'
group by status, job_name
;

STATUS               JOB_NAME             CHANKS TOTAL_DURATION_SEC
-------------------- ---------------- ---------- ------------------
PROCESSED            TASK$_59042_1             5                  9
...
PROCESSED            TASK$_59042_10            5                  7

10 rows selected.
```

Информация в этих представлениях после удаления задачи с `dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task` будет больше недоступна. Поэтому, имет смысл минимального логгирования. Например, если из логов будет известен `user_parallel_execute_tasks.job_prefix`, то можно посмотреть - где, как долго и как завершилось, так:

```
select job_name, status, run_duration, session_id, errors, output 
from  user_scheduler_job_run_details
where job_name like 'TASK$_59042%'
;
```

Если выведет примерно такое, то отработало как ожидалось:

```
TASK$_59042_7   SUCCEEDED   +00 00:00:08.000000 59,43758        
TASK$_59042_3   SUCCEEDED   +00 00:00:08.000000 41,31869            
...     
10 rows selected.
```